# iOS (iphone and ipad) refuse to show date and time in HTML emails

Tags: iphone, html-email

I built an email last christmas which displayed a series of open hours for our business. Last time out my email on acid tests looked ok. However, this year the same duplicated email is failing to display the date and time in the content list created.

christmas open hours not showing on iOS:

[image]

christmas open hours not showing in Gmail and many others
[image]

I have tried the meta solution for dates - no luck, breaking the string - no luck.

Any ideas on what else I could try.

Thanks in advance

Tim

Comment: Can't be certain without your code but I would have said you are making color of links in your email white. The links might be there but just the same color as the background making it invisible. Adding inline styles would have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit!important; 
  text-decoration: none!important; 
  font-size: inherit!important; 
  font-family: inherit!important; 
  font-weight: inherit!important; 
  line-height: inherit!important; 
}
```

Did the trick after a tweetback from someone at EOA. I had only tried the first two styles. the rest did the trick.